# which java package to use in order to read packets passed over internet and filter them

Tags: java, firewall

I am developing project in java which is going act as firewall. I blocked partticular url using read/write operation to host file.

Now, I want to block/filter the ads on the opened website. I tried using `jpcap,java.net` but it didn't help me?

Can u please suggest me which package to use in order to read packets passed over internet and filter them using java programimng language.

Thank you.

Comment: What was wrong with `java.net`?

Comment: What *specifically* did you try?  Why were `jpcap` and `java.net` unhelpful?

Comment: You can only filter packets/data when you are in the middle.  You can write a simple proxy server and have your browser use your program as a proxy server.  You can't implement a normal firewall without support from the OS.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to block/filter the ads on the opened website.

A simpler solution for blocking websites is to put dummy addresses in your hosts file for these sites.  If you add

```
127.0.0.1 www.ads.com
```

and your PC will be unable to contact that website.  On Unix you can find hosts as `/etc/hosts` and on Windows its `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

If you don't want to block whole addresses, you can implement your own proxy server and have the browser use this proxy server.

BTW: Many browsers have plugins to support ad blocking.  You might like to try these first.

Comment: hi Sir,i did this {127.0.0.1 www.ads.com }before posting this question.But now my issue blocking the ads that comes along the website which is not blocked and opened currently

Comment: You need to know a site needs to be blocked and add it to a list one way of another. What some browser plugins do is have a list already.

Comment: i actually want to block the advertisment on the opened url's webpage.for eg adsense which comes along any website

Comment: To do that you need to inspect the content, which means writing a proxy server or using a published list which is reasonably complete.

Comment: how to create proxy server in java

Comment: You create a ServerSocket service which connects to the end service on the clients behalf (with Socket) Everything you read from one socket you copy to the other.  This places you as a "Man in the middle" which means you can see/alter anything sent in either direction.

Comment: i assigned proxyport as 1234 in my mozilla browser,and wrote a socket program to read all request sent through this port.But now when i sending back the url to this port 1234 its showing connection refused,plz help

Comment: That's a good start. To support HTTP you also need to read the first line to determine which host to pass the request to.

Comment: Connection refused means there is a host with the IP address/hostname you are connecting to but there is no service listening on that port.

Comment: can it be like this my webbrowser as a client and my java program as server.i can listen(read) request sent from the browser but not able to respond back..can u just give some hint

Comment: It is more likely you need to check your browser configuration.  You need to set it up as a proxy and use the URL to connect to the Java Web server as normal.

Comment: i could load the entire raw url data to webbrowser except the images....plz help me

Comment: I would make sure you are only copying the data as binary. e.g. with `int len = inputStream.read(bytes);` and `out.write(bytes, 0, len);` If you copy images as text they will be corrupted.

Comment: u = new URL(requesturi);
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
                while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    printStream.println(inputLine);
                    printStream.flush();
                }

Comment: That is how you copy as text. It will corrupt binary data, like images.

Comment: Read my comment before yours again. ;)

Comment: hi sir,it really worked for me.but only google's search engine are not displayed throwing 403 error.can u plz suggest something

Answer (score 0):

Jpcap cannot filter packets.

Filtering packets is highly platform specific:

- Linux: you use `netfilter_queue` and `iptables`
- MacOS: you use divert sockets and `ipfw`
- Windows: you either write a driver, or use [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) (LGPL, my project) or commercial alternatives like [WinPkFilter](http://www.ntkernel.com/?Products%3aDevelopment_Toolkits%3aWindows_Packet_Filter_Kit).

These are for packet-level filtering.  This is not ideal for filtering URLs, since a single URL can be split over multiple packets.  However it works well in practice.

Also I'm not aware of Java bindings, so you'll need to write your own using JNI.